# Python Linux read process memory - int too large to convert to C long

Tags: python, linux, memory, python-2.7

I have this snippet that reads a process memory in Linux and search for a string, works ok on some distros, but on other just got this error:

```
  maps_file = open("/proc/%s/maps"%pid, 'r')
  mem_file = open("/proc/%s/mem"%pid, 'r')
  for line in maps_file.readlines():  # for each mapped region
      m = re.match(r'([0-9A-Fa-f]+)', line)
      if m.group(3) == 'r':  # if this is a readable region
          start = int(m.group(1), 16)
          end = int(m.group(2), 16)
          mem_file.seek(start)  # seek to region start
          chunk = mem_file.read(end - start)  # read region contents
          #print chunk,  # dump contents to standard output
          mem_dump = open(working_dir+"/%s.bin"%pid, "ab")
          mem_dump.write(chunk,)
          mem_dump.close()
  maps_file.close()
  mem_file.close()
```

the error:

```
scan process: 491
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./dump.py", line 106, in <module>
    MainDump(pid)
  File "./dump.py", line 79, in MainDump
    mem_file.seek(start)  # seek to region start
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

the problem line is:

```
start = int(m.group(1), 16)
```

and

```
mem_file.seek(start)
```

should I declare as `float`? Any idea?

Tried also `long()` with same result and error.

EDIT: something I forgot to say is that the error I get on an "x64" system.

Comment: Are you using 64 bit os and or 64 bit build of python? It looks like the starting address is beyond what can be handled by the C implementation, but that would suggest its compiled as a 32 bit app on a 64 bit machine?

Comment: Is distro official compiled for x64.

Comment: If you're not sure, you can always do this: `import ctypes; print(ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_long))`. If that says `4` instead of `8`, that's your problem.

Comment: I get "8" for "ctypes.c_long"

Comment: OK, next possibility: Maybe the value is > `1<<63`, which means it will fit into an unsigned long, but not a long? Can you `print hex(start)` right before the exception?

Comment: `0x7fb784d15000
0x7fff0f865000
0x7fff0f8a5000
0xffffffffff600000L
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./dump.py", line 107, in <module>
    MainDump(pid)
  File "./dump.py", line 80, in MainDump
    mem_file.seek(start)  # seek to region start
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long`

Comment: Any idea what might be?

Comment: @xtmtrx: Yes, it's exactly what I expected. `0xffffffffff600000L` will fit into an unsigned long, but not into a long. Now we just have to find the right workaround.

Comment: The workaround is `if start > sys.maxint: start -= 2*(sys.maxint+1)`.  (If anyone else wants to write it as a proper accepted answer, feel free to.)

Comment: @ArminRigo: Are you sure that `fseek` with a negative offset works on linux? On FreeBSD and OS X, it returns EINVAL. And the POSIX spec says EINVAL is returned if "… the resulting file-position indicator would be set to a negative value", so it seems like they're doing the right thing. (Also, even if it _does_ work with `fseek`, will Python's `seek` pass it through?)

Comment: @xtmtrx: Read the last paragraph of my answer first. If you never need to read the upper pages of memory anyway, you don't need a workaround for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've got the address `0xffffffffff600000L`. A (signed) C long can only hold values from `-0x8000000000000000` to `0x7fffffffffffffff`. So, this address is indeed "too large to convert to C long".

If you look at [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/fileobject.c#l695), you can see that the problem is most likely that for some reason, when Python was configured on the non-working distro, it couldn't detect that `fseeko` and `off_t` existed. But unless you want to rebuild Python, that isn't going to help you.

So, how can you work around the problem? There are a few things to try.

---

The first possibility is to seek from the end instead of the start.

```
mem_len = os.fstat(mem_file.fileno()).st_size

if start >= 1<<63L:
    mem_file.seek(mem_len - start, os.SEEK_END)
else:
    mem_file.seek(start)
```

---

You can also try this horrible hack:

```
if start >= 1<<63L:
    start -= 1<<64L
```

This will convert your `0xffffffffff600000L` to `-0xa00000`, which fits just fine into a `long`… and then hopefully, that `long` is actually being cast to some unsigned 64-bit type inside the C layer, meaning  it seeks to `0xffffffffff600000L` as you'd hoped.

---

You may also be able to get around this by using `mmap` to map the page(s) you want, instead of `seek` and `read`.

---

If worst comes to worst, you can use `ctypes` (or `cffi` or whatever you prefer) to call `fseeko` directly on your file handle.

---

Finally, make sure you actually want to read this region. I may be wrong, but I seem to remember that linux reserves the upper region for kernel pages mapped into userspace. If I'm right, the strings you're looking for aren't going to be here, so you can just skip them…

To skip processing a region, you can either move the processing inside an if:

```
start = int(m.group(1), 16)
end = int(m.group(2), 16)
if start <= sys.maxint:
    mem_file.seek(start)  # seek to region start
    chunk = mem_file.read(end - start)  # read region contents
    # ...
```

… or use a `continue` statement to skip to the next iteration of the loop:

```
start = int(m.group(1), 16)
end = int(m.group(2), 16)
if start > sys.maxint:
    continue
mem_file.seek(start)  # seek to region start
chunk = mem_file.read(end - start)  # read region contents
# ...
```

If you know the regions are always in sorted order, you can use `break` instead of `continue` (because the rest of the regions will also be out of range).

But I think the best solution is to just `try` it, and handle errors. There are other reasons this `seek` and `read` could fail—for example, if the process you're looking at unmaps a region before you get to it, or exits—and you'd rather skip the error and continue on than just exit, right?

So:

```
if m.group(3) == 'r':  # if this is a readable region
    start = int(m.group(1), 16)
    end = int(m.group(2), 16)
    try:
        mem_file.seek(start)  # seek to region start
        chunk = mem_file.read(end - start)  # read region co
    except Exception as e:
        print('Skipping region {:#018x} because of error {}'.format(start, e))
        continue
    mem_dump = open(working_dir+"/%s.bin"%pid, "ab")
    # ...
```

Comment: Just tried both, for the first one I get the same error, for the "horrible hack" I get "IOError: [Errno 0] Erro"

Comment: By the way, how can I just skip to the next process if address is like `0xffffffffff600000L` and not just exit my script?